# Does Cartesian Product and Collection of all Sets Perform a Semigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

We know that the Cartesian Product is a binary operation. Also it is an associative operation.
We know that Cartesian Product of two set is again set, there is even closure axiom.
So I need to know does Cartesian Product and Collection of all Sets Perform a Semigroup?

Comment: the binary operation goes from the set into the set again. Shouldnt it go in this case from $\mathbb K^n$ to $\mathbb K^{n+1}$? but those are different sets, right? So is it even closed under the binary operation? I'm not sure about this, but it's quite interesting.

Comment: The product is not quite associative. It is associative up to a canonical isomorphism, though.

Answer (score 1):

Is the operation indeed associative? Do we have $\left(A\times B\right)\times C=A\times\left(B\times C\right)$?
The sets are isomorphic in category $\mathbf{Set}$ wich means that
there is bijection from one to another. But that does not mean that
the sets are the same. This obstacle must somehow be 'modded' out.
If that's done then you can indeed speak of a semigroup. Associativity
is enough.

Comment: Does this "modding out" mean you're left with multiplication of cardinal numbers?

Comment: @bof: Frankly I don't know, and haven't thought about it yet. But you could be right. Looking at isomorphic sets as 'the same' point in that direction. You end up with a skeleton of the sets, so the cardinal numbers come forward. Maybe there are other ways, but I am too lazy (now) to examine them.